# Powershell Delete Computer Object

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Can some one help me on the next code im trying to run..
it seem's to be ok for me but does not delete the Object when i execute-it

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Clear-Host
$Computer = Read-Host "Type in the Host to Delete"
$rute = Get-ADComputer -Identity:"CN=$Computadora,OU=GDL,OU=ClientComputers,OU=ZAP,OU=MX,DC=kabi,DC=ads,DC=fresenius,DC=com" -Server:"DCKABI02.kabi.ads.fresenius.com"


if($rute.Contains($Computer)){
Clear-Host
Remove-ADComputer -Identity=$Computadora,OU=GDL,OU=ClientComputers,OU=ZAP,OU=MX,DC=kabi,DC=ads,DC=fresenius,DC=com" -Server:"DCKABI02.kabi.ads.fresenius.com" -Confirm:$false
#Clear-Host
Write-Host "The Computer Exist and it has been deleted" -ForegroundColor Green
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

} else{
Clear-Host
Write-Host "The Host does not exist on AD" -ForegroundColor Red
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
}
```

try to delete a Active directory object..  expected to work

Comment: If it doesn't delete the object as you expect, what *does* happen? Is there any output when you run that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not very clear and seems overengineered, `$rute.Contains($Computer)` will never ever be `$true`, you probably meant `$rute.DistinguishedName.Contains($Computer)` which could be `$true` but `.Contains` is case-sensitive so it could also be `$false`.

Your `Read-Host` statement is assigned to `$Computer` but then you're using `$Computadora`. Also, it's unclear why you are hardcoding `OU=GDL,OU=ClientComputers,OU=ZAP,OU=MX,DC=kabi,DC=ads,DC=fresenius,DC=com`, I would assume you want to use this OU as your `-SearchBase`.

Here is how you can approach and will most likely work:

```bash
$param = @{
    SearchBase = "OU=GDL,OU=ClientComputers,OU=ZAP,OU=MX,DC=kabi,DC=ads,DC=fresenius,DC=com"
    LDAPFilter = "(name={0})" -f (Read-Host "Type in the Host to Delete")
    Server     = "DCKABI02.kabi.ads.fresenius.com"
}
$computer = Get-ADComputer @param

if($computer) {
    Clear-Host
    $computer | Remove-ADComputer -Server "DCKABI02.kabi.ads.fresenius.com" -Confirm:$false
    Write-Host "The Computer Exist and it has been deleted" -ForegroundColor Green
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
else {
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "The Host does not exist on AD" -ForegroundColor Red
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
}
```